# Python - transpose a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, oracle, pandas, transpose

I would like to transpose the following dataframe in order to export it to an Oracle table.

```
0    ID                                    Available Quota  \
1  1724       GOM COD GOM HADD GOM BB GREYSOLE DABS GOM YT   
2  1578  GBE COD GBW COD GB BB GB YT SNE BB SNE YT GOM ...   
3   310  GBE COD GBW COD DABS WHAKE POLL RED SNE BB GOM BB   

0                                 Live Weight Pounds  \
1                        2328 445 3007 850 3101 1995   
2     538 5894 1755 243 490 153 3965 2727 9227 15060   
3  825 9033 1241 3120 65234 76610 1688 1195 2121 ...   

0                                              Price Date Posted  
1                                     Package $9,000        5/20  
2  $1.00 $0.40 $0.20 $1.00 $0.45 $0.50 $0.15 $0.2...        5/20  
3                                    Package $15,000        5/20
```

Ideally, the data should align like this, so that I can easily place it into my Oracle database:

[image]

And the start of the second ID's should look like this:

[image]

Original data table looks like this, my goal is only to parse the most recent date's data btw:

[image]

Using `pd.transpose` didn't change anything because my DataFrame is apparently (3, 5) and it needs to be (5, 5) in order to work. And using `pd.melt()` resulted in:

```
                     0                                              value
0                   ID                                               1724
1                   ID                                               1578
2                   ID                                                310
3      Available Quota       GOM COD GOM HADD GOM BB GREYSOLE DABS GOM YT
4      Available Quota  GBE COD GBW COD GB BB GB YT SNE BB SNE YT GOM ...
5      Available Quota  GBE COD GBW COD DABS WHAKE POLL RED SNE BB GOM BB
6   Live Weight Pounds                        2328 445 3007 850 3101 1995
7   Live Weight Pounds     538 5894 1755 243 490 153 3965 2727 9227 15060
8   Live Weight Pounds  825 9033 1241 3120 65234 76610 1688 1195 2121 ...
9                Price                                     Package $9,000
10               Price  $1.00 $0.40 $0.20 $1.00 $0.45 $0.50 $0.15 $0.2...
11               Price                                    Package $15,000
12         Date Posted                                               5/20
13         Date Posted                                               5/20
14         Date Posted                                               5/20
```

....which also won't work for an export.

My relevant code:

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            def read_html_latest(filename, **kwargs):
            #with open(filename) as f:
                text = f.read().replace('<br>', ' ')
                df = pd.read_html(text, **kwargs)[0]
                column_headers = ['ID', 'Available Quota', 'Live Weight Pounds', 'Price', 'Date Posted']
                df.columns = df.loc[0]
                df = df.loc[1:]
                return df.assign(d=pd.to_datetime(df['Date Posted'], format='%m/%d')) \
                       .query('d == d.max()') \
                       .drop('d', 1)
            df = read_html_latest(filename, attrs={'class': 'MsoNormalTable'})
            print(df)
```

Any help solving this would be greatly appreciated, thanks a lot.

Source HTML code:

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>FW: NEFS 2 Available Quota 5/21</title>
<link rel="important stylesheet" href="">
<style>div.headerdisplayname {font-weight:bold;}</style></head>
<body>
<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" class="header-part1"><tr><td><b>Subject: </b>FW: NEFS 2 Available Quota 5/21</td></tr><tr><td><b>From: </b>Claire Fitz-Gerald <claire@capecodfishermen.org></td></tr><tr><td><b>Date: </b>5/21/2014 10:08 AM</td></tr></table><br>
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; "><meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 12 (filtered medium)"><!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style><![endif]--><style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Tahoma;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book";
    panose-1:2 11 5 3 2 1 2 2 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Franklin Gothic Demi";
    panose-1:2 11 7 3 2 1 2 2 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:purple;
    text-decoration:underline;}
span.EmailStyle17
    {mso-style-type:personal;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:windowtext;}
span.title1
    {mso-style-name:title1;
    font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";
    color:#1F487E;
    font-weight:normal;}
span.EmailStyle19
    {mso-style-type:personal-reply;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#1F497D;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    font-size:10.0pt;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]--></head><body lang=EN-US link=blue vlink=purple><div class=WordSection1><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'>Please see the below quota listings.<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'>Thanks,<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><div><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'>Claire Fitz-Gerald<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><i><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></i></p><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-family:"Franklin Gothic Demi","sans-serif";color:#002776'>Cape Cod Commercial Fishermen's Alliance<o:p></o:p></span></b></p><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#DE3500'>~ Small Boats.&nbsp; Big Ideas. ~</span></b><b><span style='color:#DE3500'><o:p></o:p></span></b></p></div><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><div><div style='border:none;border-top:solid #B5C4DF 1.0pt;padding:3.0pt 0in 0in 0in'><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'>From:</span></b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'> David Leveille [mailto:nefs02@gmail.com] <br><b>Sent:</b> Wednesday, May 21, 2014 8:50 AM<br><b>To:</b> David Leveille<br><b>Subject:</b> NEFS 2 Available Quota 5/21<o:p></o:p></span></p></div></div><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:#1F487E'>AVAILABLE QUOTA FY 2014</span><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'><o:p></o:p></span></p><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="71%" style='width:71.28%'><tr><td width=220 style='width:164.95pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>ID <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=161 style='width:120.75pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-line-height-alt:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Available Quota <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=189 style='width:141.75pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-line-height-alt:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Live Weight Pounds <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=126 style='width:94.55pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-line-height-alt:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Price <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=168 style='width:125.95pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-line-height-alt:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Date Posted <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td></tr><tr><td width=220 style='width:164.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1724<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=161 style='width:120.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GOM COD<br>GOM HADD<br>GOM BB<br>GREYSOLE<br>DABS<br>GOM YT<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=189 style='width:141.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>2328<br>445<br>3007<br>850<br>3101<br>1995<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=126 style='width:94.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Package<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$9,000<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=168 style='width:125.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/20<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=220 style='width:164.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1578<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=161 style='width:120.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GBE COD<br>GBW COD<br>GB BB<br>GB YT<br>SNE BB<br>SNE YT<br>GOM BB<br>Whake<br>POLL<br>RED<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=189 style='width:141.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>538<br>5894<br>1755<br>243<br>490<br>153<br>3965<br>2727<br>9227<br>15060<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=126 style='width:94.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$1.00<br>$0.40<br>$0.20<br>$1.00<br>$0.45<br>$0.50<br>$0.15<br>$0.20<br>$0.01<br>$0.01<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=168 style='width:125.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/20<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=220 style='width:164.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>310<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=161 style='width:120.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GBE COD<br>GBW COD<br>DABS<br>WHAKE<br>POLL<br>RED<br>SNE BB<br>GOM BB<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=189 style='width:141.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>825<br>9033<br>1241<br>3120<br>65234<br>76610<br>1688<br>1195<br>2121<br>7285<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=126 style='width:94.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Package<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$15,000<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=168 style='width:125.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/20<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr style='height:23.25pt'><td width=220 style='width:164.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:23.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>347<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=161 style='width:120.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:23.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>SNE BB<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=189 style='width:141.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:23.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>8,000<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=126 style='width:94.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:23.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$0.50<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=168 style='width:125.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:23.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/7<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=220 style='width:164.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1878A<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=161 style='width:120.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GOM COD<br>GOM HADD<br>SNE BB<br>GOM BB<br>GB BB<br>GREYSOLE<br>GOM YT<br>SNE YT<br>POLL<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=189 style='width:141.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>6188<br>635<br>3916<br>7873<br>6762<br>3358<br>9776<br>271<br>186550<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=126 style='width:94.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$1.95<br>$1.35<br>$0.50<br>$0.50<br>$0.20<br>$1.40<br>$1.20<br>$0.50<br>$0.01<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=168 style='width:125.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/12<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=220 style='width:164.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1878B<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=161 style='width:120.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GBE COD<br>GBW COD<br>GB YT<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=189 style='width:141.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1113<br>12186<br>850<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=126 style='width:94.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Package<br>$10,000<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=168 style='width:125.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/12<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr></table><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>David Leveille<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>II Northeast Fishery Sector Inc.<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>10 Witham Street<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>Gloucester, MA. 01930<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>Cell 978 375 3509<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>Fax 978 281 1555<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>Web <a href="http://nefs2.com/">http://nefs2.com/</a><o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><div class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center'><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'></body></html>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you determine how many text values will be there in ' Available Quota' , I do see one or more texts. Also how do you want the Price from 2nd row?

Comment: Well there is a finite amount of species in the Available Quota column, I don't know why it only prints 7 or 8 and then puts the "..." And I edited in a pic of what the Prices in the 2nd row should look like; they should all align with their corresponding quotas

Comment: now it makes more sense thanks :)

Comment: Is the source is an excel file ?

Comment: No it's an HTML file in an email

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.read_html.html. You might be able to use this. Also post the sample source html. I will try with that sample

Comment: That's actually what I used to get this far....I'll update my post with the relevant code I'm using. The hurdle that is always in my way though, regardless of whether I use BeautifulSoup or `read_html` is that the data printout is never aligned properly so that I can export it

Comment: Lol it hasn't been fun for me being stuck on this super simple problem for so long :( but the source code has been added

Comment: 3rd row in your example has different number of 'Available Quota' & 'Live Weight Pounds'. Let me know how do you want to handle that

Comment: For that I think it'd be best to align the Quotas with the first numbers available in the Pounds column, if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works code reads through each cells, creates lists and then list to Data frame. **Note that this code will works only when number of items are same in all cell across a row.**.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Tag
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def celltext(cell):
    '''    
        textlist=[]
        for br in cell.findAll('br'):
            next = br.nextSibling
            if not (next and isinstance(next,NavigableString)):
                continue
            next2 = next.nextSibling
            if next2 and isinstance(next2,Tag) and next2.name == 'br':
                text = str(next).strip()
                if text:
                    textlist.append(next)
        return (textlist)
    '''
    textlist=[]
    y = cell.find('span')
    for a in y.childGenerator(): 
        if isinstance(a, NavigableString):
            textlist.append(str(a))
    return (textlist)

html=open('patht\to\html.html','r').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml') # Parse the HTML as a string
table = soup.find_all('table')[1] # Grab the second table

df_Quota = pd.DataFrame()

for row in table.find_all('tr'):    
    columns = row.find_all('td')
    if columns[0].get_text().strip()<>'ID':  # skip header 
        Quota = celltext(columns[1]) 
        Weight =  celltext(columns[2])
        price =  celltext(columns[3])

        Nrows= max([len(Quota),len(Weight),len(price)]) #get the max number of rows

        IDList = [columns[0].get_text()] * Nrows
        DateList = [columns[4].get_text()] * Nrows

        if price[0].strip()=='Package':
             price = [columns[3].get_text()] * Nrows

        if len(Quota)<len(Weight):  #if Quota has less itmes extened with nan
           lstnans= [np.nan]*(len(Weight)-len(Quota))
           Quota.extend(lstnans)

        FinalDataframe = pd.DataFrame(
        {
        'ID':IDList,    
         'AvailableQuota': Quota,
         'LiveWeightPounds': Weight,
         'price':price,
         'DatePosted':DateList
        })
    df_Quota= df_Quota.append(FinalDataframe)
print df_Quota
```

output

```
 AvailableQuota DatePosted     ID LiveWeightPounds            price
0        GOM COD       5/12  1878A             6188            $1.95
1       GOM HADD       5/12  1878A              635            $1.35
2         SNE BB       5/12  1878A             3916            $0.50
3         GOM BB       5/12  1878A             7873            $0.50
4          GB BB       5/12  1878A             6762            $0.20
5       GREYSOLE       5/12  1878A             3358            $1.40
6         GOM YT       5/12  1878A             9776            $1.20
7         SNE YT       5/12  1878A              271            $0.50
8           POLL       5/12  1878A           186550            $0.01
0        GOM COD       5/20   1724             2328   Package $9,000
1       GOM HADD       5/20   1724              445   Package $9,000
2         GOM BB       5/20   1724             3007   Package $9,000
3       GREYSOLE       5/20   1724              850   Package $9,000
4           DABS       5/20   1724             3101   Package $9,000
5         GOM YT       5/20   1724             1995   Package $9,000
0        GBE COD       5/20   1578              538            $1.00
1        GBW COD       5/20   1578             5894            $0.40
2          GB BB       5/20   1578             1755            $0.20
3          GB YT       5/20   1578              243            $1.00
4         SNE BB       5/20   1578              490            $0.45
5         SNE YT       5/20   1578              153            $0.50
6         GOM BB       5/20   1578             3965            $0.15
7          Whake       5/20   1578             2727            $0.20
8           POLL       5/20   1578             9227            $0.01
9            RED       5/20   1578            15060            $0.01
0        GBE COD       5/20    310              825  Package $15,000
1        GBW COD       5/20    310             9033  Package $15,000
2           DABS       5/20    310             1241  Package $15,000
3          WHAKE       5/20    310             3120  Package $15,000
4           POLL       5/20    310            65234  Package $15,000
5            RED       5/20    310            76610  Package $15,000
6         SNE BB       5/20    310             1688  Package $15,000
7         GOM BB       5/20    310             1195  Package $15,000
8            NaN       5/20    310             2121  Package $15,000
9            NaN       5/20    310             7285  Package $15,000
0         SNE BB        5/7    347            8,000            $0.50
0        GOM COD       5/12  1878A             6188            $1.95
1       GOM HADD       5/12  1878A              635            $1.35
2         SNE BB       5/12  1878A             3916            $0.50
3         GOM BB       5/12  1878A             7873            $0.50
4          GB BB       5/12  1878A             6762            $0.20
5       GREYSOLE       5/12  1878A             3358            $1.40
6         GOM YT       5/12  1878A             9776            $1.20
7         SNE YT       5/12  1878A              271            $0.50
8           POLL       5/12  1878A           186550            $0.01
0        GBE COD       5/12  1878B             1113   Package$10,000
1        GBW COD       5/12  1878B            12186   Package$10,000
2          GB YT       5/12  1878B              850   Package$10,000
```

Comment: Wow! that's nice!

Comment: Wow that looks absolutely flawless. Would it be easy to exclude all dates except the most recent one? In this case, only keep the data corresponding to 5/20 ?

Comment: In the example given has different number of items in html row 3, has 8 items in column 'Available Quota' & 10 items in  'Live Weight Pounds'. check how do you manage them

Comment: @theprowler you can filter using df_Quota.loc[df_Quota['DatePosted']=='5/20']

Comment: I keep running into the error `arrays must all be same length`. I don't understand why I get this error while you got a perfect printout ?

Comment: As I mentioned previously this is a problem with row 3 . "In the example given has different number of items in html row 3, has 8 items in column 'Available Quota' & 10 items in 'Live Weight Pounds'. check how do you want manage them". I created this output by removing 825 & 7285 from html

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense. Is there a way to just to fill those empty spots with `NaN` or leave them blank or something? Because I have 100's of these tables to parse

Comment: Ohh I just noticed....did you remove the first and last entries for ALL Quota-Weight-Prices? Because ID 1724 should have 6 values for Quota/Weight/Prices and in your printout there are only 4, with the first and last entries missing. I don't mean to keep nagging you about this issue but I just want to make sure I get this code spot on so I can immediately start using it to capture and export all this data I have

Comment: fixed both issues and note that new Nan's are added towards the end.. let me know if that works for you

Comment: I'm receiving a `syntax error` for the line `if columns[0].get_text().strip()<>'ID':  # skip header` due to the `<>`     Is that supposed to be `!=` ?

Comment: sure, change that and try

Comment: Jesus, it worked perfectly. And the line `df_Quota.loc[df_Quota['DatePosted']=='5/20']` worked perfect for sorting out all the other dates. I don't think I've ever been so elated to see results....I literally threw my arms into the air and walked away from my desk for a minute... I can't thank you enough man, you are so smart and I appreciate you helping me through these hurdles

Comment: happy to hear that... enjoy :)

Comment: Quick question. The rows are numbered but it's not a continuous count, it stops and starts over when it gets to a new cell in the original table...do you know if that's avoidable? Can it be turned into one continuous count? It's messing up my export because it stops exporting at the first break in the count

Comment: just use df_Quota= df_Quota.append(FinalDataframe, ignore_index=True)

Comment: Ohh wow that was simple, sorry I'm a noob, thanks. So it turns out my boss needs the Quotas to line up directly with the Pounds amounts in the same row...so instead of the two `NaN`s lining up with the last two Pounds amounts, is it an easy fix to make them line up with the first and last Pounds amounts (like they do in the original table)?

Comment: Hey @Shijo do you have an email address or another way to reach you? Or we could even use the chat function thru here I think? I have been making a lot of progress with this coding project I'm working on, thanks to your help, but I ran into a problem that I can't seem to figure out because I'm not that good at HTML. It's a very odd specific issue having to do with accessing the right table, so I don't think it's a proper StackOverflow question. If you can help, thank you, and if you cannot help, thanks anyway